# How to merge multiple "SELECT" statement into one?

Tags: java, sql-server, select

Currently, I am using for loop, which is unacceptably slow when `orgList` has thousands of elements inside:

```
String sql = "SELECT xua.XUAID, xua.XUA01, xua.XUA02 "
            + "FROM dbo.XDSysUseArea xua "
            + "WHERE xua.XUA03=?";

conn = ds.getConnection();
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

for(HotelSource org : orgList) {
    ps.setString(1, org.getPrimaryKey());
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        // do sth
    }
}
```

What is the right way to do the `SELECT`?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE xua.XUA03 IN (x, y, z, ...)`

Comment: @DavidG Hi David, thank you for the answer. In this way, I have to loop and construct the String "(val1,val2,val3,..)". Is this construction vulnerable? Is there any other workaround?

Comment: You can still use `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, .....)` and parameterise it properly. Which programming language are you using here?

Comment: @DavidG I am using Java

Comment: @DavidG I see. Two loops can achieve this. In the first loop, constructing (?, ?, ?, ...) for PrepareStatement. In the second loop, filling the data. Thank you for the inspiration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use SQL `IN`, for example:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE xua.XUA03 IN (x, y, z, ...)
```

You can still parameterise your query, but you need to generate the correct number of `?` in the statement. So some psuedocode here because I don't do Java:

```
String params = "?, ?, ?, ?"; //you will have to generate enough of these yourself
                              //This is an exercise for you!

String sql = "SELECT xua.XUAID, xua.XUA01, xua.XUA02 "
            + "FROM dbo.XDSysUseArea xua "
            + "WHERE xua.XUA03 IN (" + params + ")";

conn = ds.getConnection();
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

int index = 1;

for(HotelSource org : orgList) {
    ps.setString(index, org.getPrimaryKey());
    //           ^^^^^ use index here

    index++;
}

rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    // do sth
}
```

Note: The downside of this is that you mention you have thousands of entries in `orgList` which makes it really bad practice to use this method. In fact, SQL Server will not allow you to use more than a couple of thousand parameters.

Comment: I see. Two loops can achieve this. In the first loop, constructing (?, ?, ?, ...) for PrepareStatement. In the second loop, filling the data. Thank you for the inspiration

Answer (score 3):

Use `IN` operator no need to hit the query for each value

```
SELECT xua.XUAID, xua.XUA01, xua.XUA02 
FROM dbo.XDSysUseArea xua 
WHERE xua.XUA03 in (val1,val2,val3,..) -- pass the list here
```

Comment: Hi Prdp, thank you for the answer. In this way, I have to loop and construct the String "(val1,val2,val3,..)". Is there any other workaround?

Comment: @Rangtian - But you don't have to hit the query inside the loop. Should be faster

Comment: Is this way of constructing SQL String vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: I see. Two loops can achieve this. In the first loop, constructing (?, ?, ?, ...) for PrepareStatement. In the second loop, filling the data. Thank you for the inspiration

Answer (score 1):

Store org.getprimarkey() in a arraylist  `List<Integer>` past it to where clause using in operator

`SELECT xua.XUAID, xua.XUA01, xua.XUA02 "
            + "FROM dbo.XDSysUseArea xua "
            + "WHERE xua.XUA03 IN (mylist);`

NOTE: replace [ ] in list using replaceall method.

Comment: Upvoting it also helps :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use operator IN for this purpose. Example,

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);
```